# What options are there for converting a .NET console application to client/server?

Tags: c#, console-application, remote-desktop

I have console applications that run on remote servers.  Right now I'm connecting to remote desktop and running them.

I'm thinking of setting things up so I can run my console programs in "server mode" or "client mode" such that they can be launched from anywhere.

So starting with a regular application:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
   Console.Write("Hello {0}", args[0]);
}
```

To something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
   string mode = args.First();
   if(mode == "local")
      Run(args.Skip(1));
   else if(mode == "server")
      Run(WaitForArgsFromRemoteClient());
   else if(mode == "client")
      SendArgsToRemoteServer(args[1], args.Skip(2));
}

static void Run(string[] args) {
   Console.Write("Hello {0}", args[1]);
}
```

I've never implemented this exact scenario.  Should I be looking at WCF?  If so, what specific part of it?

I'm just looking for a simple mechanism to save me from logging in remotely to run a console application.

Comment: Have you considered just using Powershell and [remote commands](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/)?

Comment: nope, but I will certainly follow your link and check that out.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To setup networking between client and server you can use a simple .Net networking library such as [lidgren-network-gen3](https://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/wiki/Basics). Very simple to setup communication between running .Net console applications. This would require a server application to be running all the time on the remote server though so may not be best for you.